# NDepend: View All Issues for a class

Tags: ndepend

Is it possible in NDepend to view all the violated rules for a given class or method.

We have just started using NDepend and currently have many rule violations. It would be really useful when refactoring a class to be able to see in one place all the violations that are applicable to that piece of code.

Comment: This feature is not available yet, and it'll be certainly implemented for 2016. You can vote for it here  http://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/4558366-list-rules-violations

Comment: For now you can write a short program based on NDepend.API that would let you list the issues for a specific class. http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html